# mac osx: how to cd to the folder with a name which the first character is "-"?

Tags: macos, cd

There is a foler which name is "-Tmp-", how can I `cd` into it?

When I use `cd`, it prompt as:

```
$ cd -Tmp-/
cd: -T: invalid options
```

Anybody can help me?

Comment: Belongs to apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: @thSoft Better to http://unix.stackexchange.com/ since this is a *nix feature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `--` to stop argument parsing.

```
$ cd -- -Tmp-
```

Comment: ...Good. I was actually typing my answer with same content as yours and then see SO's notifying me there's an answer to be loaded..

Comment: Posted at the same time as me with a better answer.